# MySql View with ranked rows

Tags: mysql

I have a view named "vw_season_score"  which returns this result with the following query;

```
SELECT s.* FROM vw_season_one_score s
```

[image: query1result]

If I add this to the query I get the positions:

```
SELECT  @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS position, s.* FROM vw_season_one_score s
JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
```

[image]

However if I Try to create a view using the following query...

```
CREATE VIEW vw_season_one_positions AS 

SELECT  @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS position, s.* FROM vw_season_one_score s
JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r;
```

I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1351. View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter
```

So how can I make this view with the positions included ?

Thanks in advance for your help and taking the time to read this.

Comment: I can't test at this moment, but will it allow you to create the view if you wrap it as `CREATE VIEW... AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT @curRow := @curRow + 1.....) sub);` ? The error complains of the view's _SELECT_ having a variable, but doesn't imply it one cannot appear _anywhere_.

Comment: Hi Michael, this will produce a subquery in view error, not a viable option.

Comment: You can't use variables in a view: From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html): _The SELECT statement cannot refer to system variables or user-defined variables._

Comment: Ok, we already know that by the error code output, any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Comment: what rank should they get if their scores are equal?

Comment: The rank is based on the score column from the highest to the lowest one. which is 6 for the first position, 5 for the second and 2 for the third as shown in the posted images.

Comment: 'sample data' is notoriously non-indicative of the entire problem domain. anyway, the answer remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ranking is in order of score (you didn't include an order by), and assuming that two teams with the same score get the same rank, and assuming that if you have ranks `1, 2, 2, ..` there will be no rank `3` and it will skip straight to `4`, you can use the following query that is potentially horribly performing, but will get the job done:

```
select *, 1 + (select count(score) from vw_season_one_score where t.score < score) as rank
  from vw_season_one_score t
  order by score desc;
```

You can use this query as the basis for your view.

If there are no duplicate scores, this will give you a nice rank of `1, 2, ..., n` with no repeats.

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f585fc/1)

Comment: The order by clause it's already implemented in the view, I forgot to add that info, however It's an intersting analysis you've made with the tied scores that makes me think if the view it's the best approach for this case, besides that, your answer works perfectly, thank you!